# How to plot Horizontal bar graph from a dictionary using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using:

```
plt.bar(range(len(d)), d.values(), align='center')
plt.yticks(range(len(d)), d.keys())
plt.xlabel('frequency', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('keywords', fontsize=18)

plt.show()
```

and I am getting the output below:
[image]

but I want to show the corresponding bar for each keyword on the y-axis, rather than the x-axis. How can I achieve that?

Comment: read matplot doc: [matplot bar()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar)

Comment: It looks like you are setting `yticks` the keys of the dictionary. Maybe you want to do that for `xticks`?

Comment: But then it will plot keywords on x-axis. I have to plot keywords on y-axis and corresponding horizontal bar with corresponding values on x-axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using matplotlib's [`barh()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.barh) function will create a horizontal bar chart for you:

```
plt.barh(range(len(d)), d.values(), align='center')
```

From the docs:

> `matplotlib.pyplot.barh(bottom, width, height=0.8, left=None, hold=None, **kwargs)`
>
> Make a horizontal bar plot with rectangles bounded by:
>
> `left, left + width, bottom, bottom + height`
>
> (left, right, bottom and top edges)
>
> bottom, width, height, and left can be either scalars or
>   sequences

Also see the `barh` demo on the matplotlib gallery page [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.html)

Comment: Thankyou for the answer.. yeah everytime i was missing barh.

Answer (score 0):

Use `plt.barh()` rather than using the vertical bar chart function.